# Create relation matrices from a given cell-array of strings (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have 2 sequences in a cell-array  :

```
 Input_cell= {'ABC','ACB'}
 S1= 'ABC' % which means A<B<C
 S2= 'ACB' % which means A<C<B
```

I want to convert each of the strings in the `Input_cell` into a matrix `M[i,j]` which has to satisfy those conditions :

```
       M[i,j] , M[j,i] are random
       M[i,i] =0.5
       M[i,j] + M[j,i] = 1
       M[i,j] < M[j,i] % For example: if A<B then M[A,B] < M[B,A]


%// For example: if we have S1 = 'ABC'  (which means `A<B<C`), the M1 matrix will  be expected as follows:

     A      B    C    
  A  0.5    0    0   
  B  1     0.5   0  
  C  1      1   0.5   


%// If we have S2 = 'ACB' (which means `A<C<B`), the M2 matrix will be expected as follows:
     A      B    C    
  A  0.5    0    0   
  B  1     0.5   1  
  C  1      0   0.5
```

How to create that kind of above matrices from a given cell-array of sequences?

Comment: do you have a naive attempt to show over there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%get the ordering, where '312' would mean that A is largest, then C, then B
[~,k]=sort(S2);
%compare each pair
bsxfun(@(a,b)(a<b)+0.5*(a==b),k,k')
```

Comment: how to generate the 2 matrices at a time from the given cell-array Input-cell = { 'ABC', 'ACB'} ?

Comment: Use a loop and iterate through.